# Make controller clean and readable in laravel 5.2 (defining validation specially)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a registration form. I'm validating fields in Controller.
but **it's not good and my controller will be messy.**
Actually I want my controller clean and readable.
How can I define validations in another way like in a specific class?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|min:4|max:64|unique:users|regex:/[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',
        'email' => 'required|email|min:8',
        'title' => '|max:32',
        'full_name' => '|max:32',
        'address' => 'required|max:200',
        'password' => array(
            'required',
            'confirmed',
            'regex:/xx/',
            'min:8'),
        'phone' => 
        'mobile' => 
        'image' => 'size:200',]);
```

Comment: I think you should read the documentation, and search the web first before submitting new questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation) objects and define validation there.

So in your example you could create **RegisterUserRequest**

```
php artisan make:request RegisterUserRequest
```

then you can move your validation rules to **app/Http/Requests/RegisterUserRequest** **rules()** method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required|min:4|max:64|unique:users|regex:/[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',
        'email' => 'required|email|min:8',
        'title' => '|max:32',
        'full_name' => '|max:32',
        'address' => 'required|max:200',
        'password' => array(
            'required',
            'confirmed',
            'regex:/xx/',
            'min:8'), 
        'image' => 'size:200'
    ];
}
```

there is also the **authorize()** method, within which, you may check if the authenticated user actually has the authority to update/create/delete a given resource. (return true/false accordingly).

Then in your controller inject your FormRequest object:

```
public function store(RegisterUserRequest $request)
{
    // your other non-validation code
}
```

Now your validation will be checked before the actual code of **store()** method is executed.

If you are interested in how that works check the **Illuminate\Routing\Controller** and there the **Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests** trait.